# How to disable one button , while the other buttons are stil able

Tags: javascript, button, disable

I have a store were I want it to be possible to click on a product until the stock is out. The stock is 10. How can I make so only the clicked button disables when reached 10 clicks, and the other ones continue working? Stock is Lager = 10. Products is the array. The buttons are hardcoded in html.

Its failing when I have clicked more than 10 times on one product. I want that the clicked products button get disabled. Its out of stock. Now I can continue pressing the button even after inCart is over 10.

```
let cartNr = document.getElementById('cartNr')
const lang1 = document.querySelector('.lang1')
cartNr = 1

let products = [
    {
        id: 0,
        namn: 'Sneaker1',
        img: 0,
        pris: 1500,
        lager: 10,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        namn: 'Sneaker2',
        img: 1,
        pris: 1500,
        lager: 10,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        namn: 'Sneaker3',
        img: 2,
        pris: 1500,
        lager: 10,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        namn: 'Sneaker4',
        img: 3,
        pris: 1500,
        lager: 10,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        namn: 'Sneaker5',
        img: 4,
        pris: 1500,
        lager: 10,
        inCart: 0
    }
]



 const euro = document.querySelectorAll('.euro')


for(let i = 0; i < euro.length; i++ ){
    euro[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i])
        totalCost(products[i])
        
         if(products[i].inCart >= 10){
            euro[i].disabled = true
        }
           
        
        
        
       
    })
}

    
         


  function onLoadCartNumbers(){
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers')
    if(productNumbers){
        lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${cartNr = productNumbers}</div>`
    }

}

  function cartNumbers(product){
    console.log('the product clicked is', product)
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers')
    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers)
    if(productNumbers){
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1)
        lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${cartNr = productNumbers +1}</div>`
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1 )
        lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${cartNr = 1}</div>`
    }
   
    setItems(product)
    
  }

  

  function setItems(product){
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart')
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems)
    console.log(cartItems) //funkar
    if(cartItems != null){
        if(cartItems[product.img] == undefined){
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [product.img]: product
            }
            console.log(cartItems)
        }else {
        cartItems[product.img].inCart += 1
        console.log(cartItems) //funkar
        }
    }
    else{
        product.inCart = 1
        cartItems = {
            [product.img]: product
    }
    console.log(cartItems)//funkar
  
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart',JSON.stringify(cartItems))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('productsInCart'))
}

  function totalCost(product){
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost')
    if(cartCost != null){
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost)
        localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost + product.pris)
    }
    else{
        localStorage.setItem('totalCost', product.pris)
    }
    
  }

  async function patchPost(obj){
    const baseURL = `https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/`
    const url = baseURL + `Products.json`
        const init = {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(obj),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            }
        };
    
        const response = await fetch(url, init)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        
    }
     let obj = Object.values(products) 
    patchPost(obj)
    console.log(obj)

  onLoadCartNumbers()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `products[i]` and `euro[i]` instead of the `.map(..)` and `for` loop. That looks something like `euro[i].disabled = products[i].inCart >= 10` instead of all that looping.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried `if(products[i].inCart >= 10){
            euro[i].disabled = true
        }` but the button stil dont disable after 10 click

Comment: That may be because you're not changing the `inCart` property properly.

Comment: What do you mean with not changing the inCart properly?

Comment: I mean that the problem may be that the `products[i].inCart >= 10` condition is always `false` that may be because `products[i].inCart` is not changed correctly. How that is done is not evident from the code that you've provided, it probably happens in the `cartNumbers` or `totalCost` function.

Comment: I dont really get what you are meaning. products is the array. I dont use it in those other functions.

Comment: So, as I see it, when you click an `euro` button, the product (an item from the `products` array) associated with that button will have its `inCart` property changed by one. if the `products[i].inCart >= 10` is `false`, that means that the `inCart` property of that product is not increased correctly.

Comment: ah okey! Thank you. Yes its increased correctly, that works just fine! Do you want me to add more of my code in the question?

Comment: Yes, that will be helpful. Add the latest code that you're using and describe how it fails.

Comment: Now I have added the code in js file. the products are hardcoded in html aswell with button class euro. here is github for the project https://github.com/Astborg/FE22-js2-mp3-Josefin-Astborg

Comment: The only thing I see is thing `cartItems[product.img].inCart += 1` which seems to increase the `inCart` value for something that you've retrieved from storage, you'll also need to increase the count for the corresponding `products` item. You can just add this `product.inCart++` after that line.

Comment: Also, in the `setItems` you modify something that you get from localStorage but you never save it back to localStorage. Maybe that is done somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you Ill try this tomorrow when Im back on my laptop.

Comment: Now it works! thank you so much! The only thing is that for the first product it disables at 10, the second product at 11 and third at 12 enz.. How can I fix that?